# How to end or fail AWS Glue job with error?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Consider an AWS Glue job snippet:

```
val input = glueContext
  .getCatalogSource(database = "my_db", tableName = "my_table")
  .getDynamicFrame()
val myLimit = 10    
if (input.count() <= myLimit) {
  // end glue job here with error
}
// continue execution
```

How do I exit the job with an error status? If I just skip execution, it simply ends as successful; if I throw an exception, it fails with an exception. Can I just invoke something to stop the job with a fail/error status but without throwing an exception?

**UPDATED**

At first glance I can:

```
val spark: SparkContext = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
val glueContext: GlueContext = new GlueContext(spark)
val jobId = GlueArgParser.getResolvedOptions(sysArgs, Seq("JOB_ID").toArray)("JOB_ID")
spark.cancelJob(jobId)
```

But:

1. `SparkContext` is from the inner framework and ending the job can lead to unpredictable (unstable) results.
2. `org.apache.spark.SparkContext#cancelJob` receives `Int` while AWS Glue has a `String` `JOB_ID` like this: `j_aaa11111a1a11a111a1aaa11a11111aaa11a111a1111111a111a1a1aa111111a`. So it cannot be passed to `cancelJob` directly.

Comment: Why do not throw RuntimeException ?

Comment: Why do not end job without stacktrace? ;)

Comment: Any idea how to read data directly from the database(jdbc) without using crawler?  getSource method can be used but how to properly specify JsonOptions? Any help help would be helpful. Very less documentation available for scala

Comment: He he, I fill your pain. :) I did not try jdbc, but crawlers are not used for creating connection. They are used for scaning your data and build table in glue datalake. They are not related to any data reading. :) Look at [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-samples)

Comment: What about print(error) followed by job.commit()?

Answer (score 0):

This is written as pyspark, as it's what I know

```
args = getResolvedOptions(
   sys.argv, ["TempDir", "JOB_NAME"]
)
job = Job(glue_context)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

if my_check() == False:
    # you can use any other exit code and glue will still report failure
    # because the job is not committed
    sys.exit(0)

do_normal_stuff()
job.commit()
```

The spark job and glue job are different things, which is why you can't interchange their IDs.